# Override Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Option_Value

Tags: magento

how can i override Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Option_Value?

my config.xml:

```
<config>
<modules>
    <My_Module>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </My_Module>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <catalog_resource>
            <rewrite>
                        <product_option_type_price>
                            My_Module_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Option_Value
                        </product_option_type_price>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog_resource>
    </models>
</global>
```

and my class

```
class My_Module_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Option_Value 
extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Option_Value
{ }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeach sure You can, but config.xml should look like:

```
<catalog_resource>
    <rewrite>
         <product_option_value>My_Module_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Option_Value</product_option_value>
    </rewrite>
</catalog_resource>
```

Pay attention on text wrap in 3rd line, everything must be in one line